# How can I call an action in a reducers?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to call up an action in the redaction and I do not quite understand how to do this

```
...
import { loaderStart, loaderStop } from '../actions/loaders';

const loaders = dispatch => ({
  loaderStart: text => dispatch(loaderStart({ text })),
  loaderStop: text => dispatch(loaderStop({ text })),
});

....
loaders.loaderStart('uploadFiles'); // is not a function
```

I understand that I need a "dispatch" but how do I transfer it here?

actions

```
export const loaderStart = text => ({
  type: LOADER_START,
  payload: text,
});

export const loaderStop = text => ({
  type: LOADER_STOP,
  payload: text,
});
```

Comment: You mean that you would like to call a action in reducer from a component? right

Comment: You are using redux right?

Comment: I have an action that causes images to be uploaded to the server, and I want that when the download starts, another action is called, which returns the boot state. To do this, in the reducers of the download, I'm trying to call an action creator

Answer (score 0):

Your loaders is not an object, it's a function. You'd have to call `loaders(dispatch).loaderStart('uploadFiles')` to make it work.

Comment: dispatch is not defined

Comment: Ok, so, you are calling this from a reducer, right? Could you pate the code of that reducer? And maybe the first action that calls it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to call an action implementation in REDUCER from a component, you will need to do this

```
loaders(dispatch).loaderStart('uploadFiles')
```

This should work.